# Android Spinner text difference

Tags: kotlin, spinner

I'm adding two different spinners to my XML layout, one thats filled through an XML file and one thats filled programmatically.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spDevice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/spinner_data"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
```

So the one Spinner is filled through this XML file, which goes great and gives  a good clear text quality.

```
<resources>
<string-array name="spinner_data">
    <item>Alle apparaten</item>
    <item>Light</item>
    <item>Door Sensor</item>
    <item>Socket</item>
    <item>Smart meter</item>
    <item>Multi sensor</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="solo_data">
    <item>Hele huis</item>
</string-array>
```

The other spinner gets filled programmatically, with the following code:

```
private var roomDtoList: ArrayList<RoomItemDto> = ArrayList()
private var spRoomData : ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()

private fun fillSpRooms(){
    spRoomData.clear()

    for(item in roomDtoList){
        spRoomData.add(item.name)
    }
    var spAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter<String>(this.context, R.layout.spinner_drop_layout, R.id.spinnerTextview, spRoomData)
    spHome!!.adapter = spAdapter
}
```

So whenever I fill this spinner with the following code, the filled text looks ugly and has no margin/spacing between every line. Even when I add margin and textStyling into the R.id.spinnerTextview, it won't make the text look clear.

Anyone knows a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this. Hope this will help.

```
    for(item in roomDtoList){
        spRoomData.add(item.name)
    }

    spHome!!.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using a simple spinner layout and languages array
    val aa = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spRoomData)
    // Set layout to use when the list of choices appear
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    // Set Adapter to Spinner
    spHome!!.setAdapter(aa)
```

Comment: Hey, already tried this but it won't help. As it gives an error that I must set an ID for the TextView.